Can we allocate Stack Memory at Runtime?
When a function recursively calls itself and stores the previous state in the stack, can we call the memory as runtime allocated? These call stack memory are not allocated at compile time, so is it safe to conclude that we can allocate stack memory at runtime?
I'm a bit confused by materials on the web that state Runtime Memory Allocation is the other name of Dynamic Memory Allocation, which I think is oversimplification.

It's a platform feature so please tag your question with os you are using.  With Linux you can use pthread_attr_setstack to set the stack size of a thread before creating the thread at run-time.  ulimit and at run-time setrlimit() is used to set the stack size (upto hard limit) before creating a process.  I don't think it's possible to change the size for an existing process/thread.

A stack frame's size is mostly set at compile time with the parameters of the functions and local variables. Some compilers provide a function called alloca that lets you allocate dynamically on the stack.
Allocation of stack frames is done at runtime through your OS.

As Allan explains, it is OS dependent. When a function call is made, memory for the function stack frame is reserved. For example, Linux reserves a 4M stack and Windows a 1M stack by default. The memory location where the reservation begins is saved so on function return execution can pick back up there. Your local variables are provide with storage from that block. How much of the stack fame is used depends on the number of local variables used. In a recursive case, the next function stack frame will begin after the memory for local variables for the current (and a red-zone in x86_64).

I would say a function call will use previously allocated stack space.  The man page for alloca() says "allocates size bytes of space in the stack frame" but it's on the (pre-allocated) stack frame.

See Stack frame layout on x86-64

Stack memory is always run-time allocated, but the C language specifically does not mention how/where allocation is done. And consequently C doesn't let us manipulate the stack directly, which is a good thing.
Some non-standard functions like alloca may allow stack allocation. It is also very likely that variable-length arrays (VLA) are stack allocated. In either case, the lib or compiler handles the allocation/deallocation, like with any stack memory.
"Runtime memory allocation" and even "dynamic memory allocation" are not formal terms, so they could mean anything. Although dynamic memory allocation is a common de facto standard name for allocated storage/free store/heap allocation... or whatever else it might be called. The formal term used by the C standard is allocated storage.
